# Replace String not working in robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I wanna replace a string in a json file that popup in the application. I'm using robot framework 4.0 with python 3.92 on win32.

I have tried several way of replace a string with a given condition but no luck yet. Here are some of scripts i have tried so far

```
Replace a String
  ${result}=  Replace String  "abc123"  "abc123"  "abc123-Pizza"
  Should be equal  ${result}  "abc123-Pizza" 

Replace a String
  Get File  import_file\\abc_123.json
  ${result}=  Replace String  "abc123"  "abc123"  "abc123-Pizza"
 Should be equal  ${result}  "abc123-Pizza"
  Sleep  30s

Replace a String
    ${template}  Get File  test-abc123\\import_file\\abc_123.json
${template}=  Replace String  "name": "abc123"  "name": "abc123"  "name": "abc123-Pizza"
Should Be Equal  ${template}  "name": "abc123-Pizza"
Sleep
...  30s
${template}  Create File  test-abc123\\import_file\\abc_123.json
```

Above is the script i have tried. The json files is open sucessfully within the apps. Unfortunately, the logs gives me green but its actually a failure. no string is replaced at all.
Any idea how to solve  this?

Comment: i tried your first example and it works fine. In result there is "abc123-Pizza". What do you want from this code? For your purpouse it would be better to use [evaluate](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword and work with it as json instead of string.

Comment: It replace your string? I can get green logs, but while it running and I monitor I din see any changes on the json file.

Comment: The keyword simply replaces the string. If you use Log  ${result} you should be able to see that it is changed

Comment: Really? okay let me try again.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as expected.

```
Replace a String
    ${template}=  Get File  test-abc123\\import_file\\abc_123.json
    ${replaced_template}=  Replace String  ${template}  "name": "abc123"  "name": "abc123-Pizza"
    Should Be Equal  ${replaced_template}  "name": "abc123-Pizza"
    Create File    test-abc123\\import_file\\abc_123.json    ${replaced_template}
```